# mysql avoid displaying results twice from 2 conditions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have these 2 statements:

> $pow= mysql_query("select options.label from options where userid='1'");

and:

> $sql=("SELECT options.label from options WHERE userid=''");
>
> $result= mysql_query($sql);

the first one would return the rows where the userid equals 1 and the second one where the are no user ids. the issue I am having is sometimes we have results with with the same label and userid=1 AND userid=''
the labels are echoed on the page. I would like to return every label 1 time even if the row occurs twice.
 In other words I need the results that have userid=1 AND at the same time userid='' BUT if the field label is repeated, to show it only once.

Comment: Use `distinct` key word like `select distinct(options.label) from options where userid='1'`

Comment: thats not going to return the second results. In other words I need the results that have userid=1 AND at the same time userid='' BUT if the field label is repeated, to show it only once.

Comment: Combine both into one statement `select distinct(options.label) from options where userid='1' or userid=""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select distinct(options.label) from options where userid='1' or userid=""
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `distinct`

```
select distinct options.label from options where userid='1'
```